# WCF function in ASP.NET Core app not available

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I just try to use a WCF service in ASP.NET core. The service works and I get the results I want.

WCF Code:

```
public List<SelectMaschines> Maschinen(SelectMaschines c_Auswahl)
{
   do something that works;
   return lst_masch;
}


public interface I_DO_Service
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<SelectMaschines> Maschinen(SelectMaschines var123);

    [OperationContract]
    SelectReasons Prod2(SelectReasons var231);
}
```

Also the implemention into the core project works. But the defined functions are not available only as Async.
[image: test]

So is there a difference in ASP.NET core to call a WCF or can I just use Async functions?

Comment: Change your action into an asynchronous one. You can create a WCF proxy to call any standards-compliant SOAP service. In ASP.NET Core the generated proxies use async methods for service operations by default, as they should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For WCF in Asp.Net Core, there are only `Async` method will be generated for client code, which mean you **can and should** use `Async` functions.

This is due to that `SynchronizationContext` is removed from Asp.Net Core, it will not be able to use `Sync` WCF method under `.net core`.

So, for your issue, change `Index` to `async Task<IActionResult>`, and call WCF Service by `Async` method.

Comment: Thank you. Now it works. From that point i can look for more detailed informations of async.

Answer (score 1):

I think the async here means that your asp.net core will call the wcf asynchronously.

So yes, use the async function like:

`var var_list = await i_DO_Service.MaschinenAsync();`

Comment: Thanks Obay. Your answer was also part of the solution but Edward was more detailed.